# Graphql how to upload multiple files and not just one

Tags: express, upload, graphql

Hi everyone I have a graphql resolvers for uploading an image. The thing is that I want to upload multiple images to I keep getting a error. Here is my code. What is the correct way of uploading a multiple images on a graphql server?

Resolver

```
export const uploadImage = async (_, { files }, context) => {
  await jwtAuthentication.verifyTokenMiddleware(context);
  console.log(file);

  try {
    let fileArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const stream = createReadStream();
      const pathname = path.join(__dirname, `/public/images/${files[i].filename}`);
      await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(files[i].pathname));
      fileArr.push({ path: `${apiUrl}/images/${files[i].filename}` });
    }

    //save image to document

    return fileArr;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // graphqlError(error);
  }
};
```

TypeDefs

```
  type ImageUploadResult {
    path: String
  }
  extend type Mutation {
    uploadImage(files: [Upload]): [ImageUploadResult]
    createImage(imageInput: ImageInput): Image!
    removeImage(_id: ID): Image!
  }
```

Frontend query

```
export const UPLOAD_IMAGE = gql`
  mutation($files: [Upload]) {
    uploadImage(files: $files)
  }
`;
```

Frontend upload function

```
  const uploadFiles = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const response = await GraphqlRequest(auth.token).request(UPLOAD_IMAGE, { files });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: what error/where?